# What is the simplest way to test a plain socket server

Tags: macos, terminal, sockets

I have a server which listens on a socket for incoming connections and outputs a welcome text ("Hello world"). What is the simplest way to test this with plain tools from the operating system (here OS X)? I'd imagine something like a good old RS232-terminal application:

```
mac:~ mike$ terminal 192.168.92.123 1234
Hello world
>
```

Comment: This is a port, not a socket. If you actually want to test a socket, you should use `nc -U` on OS X and on Linux, use `socat`, e.g. `socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/memcached.sock`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Depends on the kind of tests you want to run? If you want to test establishing a connection and sending some data I can think of two simple tests. Use `netcat` (nc) to "echo" some data into a remote socket, or use telnet to connect to it interactively.

If your server is listening on foobar.com, port 1234 you could test it like this:

```
bro@host:~ $ echo "Some data to send" | nc foobar.com 1234
```

Same address/port as above, but make the session interactive:

```
bro@host:~ $ telnet foobar.com 1234
Trying foobar.com...
Connected to foobar.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Type some data to send here
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried telnet, but it timed out. As I found out, it was a firewall issue.